# MySQL conditional table structure question

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mySQL and am trying to create a database for an add item page which will have inputs: `name` `price` and `type`. Type can be either 'Book', 'Audiobook' or 'Ebook' and depending on which type is selected, new input fields will be added to the page. If 'Book' is selected, inputs `number-of-pages`, `weight` and `hardcover(boolean value)` will be added. If 'Audiobook' is selected input `length` will be added. If 'Ebook' is selected input `format` will be added.

My question is what's the best table structure for this. Should this be done using one table or should I create four tables, one for generic item attributes and the other three for the attributes of specific item types like this:

```
//item table

id  name    price   type
=============================
1   item1   22      Audiobook
2   item2   15      Book
```

```
//book table

id  pageNum    weight   hardcover
=================================
1   340        22       yes
2   679        15       no
```

```
//audiobook table

id  length
============
1   12:30h
2   6:00h
```

```
//ebook table

id  format
============
1   pdf
2   epub
```

If so what would the query for joining the item table with the relevant table and inserting the data into the database look like?

Comment: For flexibility, a common design is a generic attribute-value table.